# //div[@id='resultStats']" Error

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

i want to get the google results as div. but i take error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

my code:

```
var doc = new HtmlWeb().Load("http://www.google.com/search?q=love");
var div = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='resultStats']");
var text = div.InnerHtml.ToString();         <---    this line
textBox1.Text = div.ToString();
var matches = Regex.Matches(text, @"About ([0-9,]+) ");
var total = matches[0].Groups[1].Value;
```

i try this code:

```
int counter = 0;
HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = hw.Load("http://www.google.com/search?q=love");
foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
{
    counter = counter + 1;
}
MessageBox.Show(counter.ToString());
```

i see 97 in the messagebox.

but i try this code:

```
HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = hw.Load("http://www.google.com/search?q=love");
foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
{
    MessageBox.Show(link.ToString());
}
```

i see  "HtmlAgiliytPack.HtmlNode" in the messagebox 97 times.

Comment: Perhaps `ToString()` is not the method you are looking for.

Comment: Step through your code in the debugger and look at what `div` and `link` contain. Hint: they're not strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first error is because your loaded HTML doesn't contain `<div>` element with `id='resultStats'`. That's why your `div` variable is `null`, and hence `div.InnerHtml` gives you a `NullReferenceException`.

As to the second issue: by using `link.ToString()` you call `.ToString()` method of variable of type `HtmlNode` which seems is not overloaded, and returns just a short type name. I suspect you want to output the link node itself. To do this just use `.OuterHtml` property on your link:

```
MessageBox.Show(link.OuterHtml);
```

---

Just a side note: the `HtmlNode.InnerHtml` property is a type of `string`, so calling `ToString()` method on a type of `string` is not necessary here.

Comment: thanks for reply. i understand. but i want to get resultsstats div on the google search result page???